# Available element not found in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a very complex and non public selenium script to perform GUI tests. When running the tests locally everything works fine. But when I run the exact same tests inside a docker image (used on jenkins), the tests do not run through. An element is not found in the webpage.

The following is a part where I wait for an input box to appear and to fill in some text:

```
    self._handler.log("B")
    elem = WebDriverWait(self._handler.webdriver, 30).\
            until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Create new collab']"))) # TIMEOUT

    self._handler.log("C")
    elem.clear()
    self._handler.log("D")
    elem.send_keys(collab_name)
```

I get a timeout error in the `WebDriverWait` line.

I save the page source in the `log` step (just before the `WebDriverWait` line), and see the following part in the html:

```
 <div class="md-tab container-centered" id="create" style="width: 988px; left: 988px;">
         <div class="md-input-container md-theme-default md-input-placeholder md-input-focused">
          <label>
           Collab Name
          </label>
          <input class="md-input" placeholder="Create new collab" type="text"/>
          <!-- -->
          <!-- -->
          <!-- -->
         </div>
```

So the element is available in the page source, and visible as well (as the following screenshot made at step 'B' reveals):

[image]

What is going on? A bug in selenium?

**Addendum**

What I tried as well is the following chain:

```
    elem = WebDriverWait(self._handler.webdriver, 30).\
            until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='create']//input")))

    actions = ActionChains(self._handler.webdriver)
    actions.move_to_element(elem)
    actions.send_keys(collab_name)
    actions.perform()
```

But in this case the input field is not populated by the text in `collab_name`. The input field stays empty.

Comment: I think the div maybe outside the viewport. The style mentions left coordinate as 988px and a similar width. Try with presence_of_element_located wait. Then use `ActionChains` to move to this element and then clear the text and then try to enter text.

Comment: @Grasshopper: Thanks for the suggestion, but when I try that the text is not sent to the input box. It stays empty.

Comment: I added this alternative approach to my original question.

Comment: You will need to clear the existing placeholder text first. Then enter text. Move to the element using actions. try clear() on elem variable and then send_keys

Comment: @Grasshopper: Nope does not work. I am using `elem.clear()` at different locations, but it does not change the outcome.

Comment: Just to be clear the placeholder text remains even after sendkeys? What happens if after moving to the element u send a click action? Does the cursor move to the input box and blink?

Comment: I probably found what was missing: actions.click()...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use visibility_of_element_located instead of presence_of_element_located. There is a small difference between both. Altough the element could be present it does not mean that it is also already visible.

That the element is visible on the screenprint means that it was visible at the moment of making this screenprint wich is probably just after the exception occurs.

Comment: When using `visibility_of_element_located` I run into a Timeout error at the `WebDriverWait` step.

Comment: Also when you run the test locally?

Comment: Is it the first element you're trying to interact with on this page?

Comment: Is the XPath leading to a unique element or is the XPath locator results in more then one node, the other being not visible? Probably an unnecessary question because locally it's working fine.